# Invoke a AWS Lambda function via Google App Script

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, lambda, google-apps-script, aws-api-gateway

I need to invoke an AWS Lambda function from within a Google Sheet following any changes to the spreadsheet. I have a Google App Script that executes when any changes are made to the spreadsheet but need an http request to trigger a Lambda function.

The Lambda function will be NodeJS and contain a gsjson package (that converts a Google Sheet to JSON) and then move the newly created JSON file to S3 using either S3Cmd or trigger another S3 Lambda function that can move files to S3 buckets:

**Google Sheet->Google App Script->Trigger AWS API Gateway?**

**Lambda function(NodeJS)->gsjson npm module->Create JSON file->Move JSON file to S3 bucket**

What action/trigger can be used to invoke a Lambda function/AWS Gateway API from inside a Google App Script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What action/trigger can be used to invoke a Lambda function/AWS
>   Gateway API from inside a Google App Script?

An HTTP request to an AWS API Gateway endpoint (aka GET/POST/etc. some URL) would work. API Gateway can be configured to trigger a Lambda function whenever that endpoint is invoked.

Take a look at the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-intro.html).

Here is a relevant [AWS Tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ZyicyDpqE0&list=PL5zjQdAWZiUwdgZK858EtuKiK7WF_2qKF) to complement.

Comment: Thanks Raphael. Any syntax ideas for the HTTP request in the Google App Script? Is it just a case of pointing to the webhook URL within the Google App Script?

Comment: This may help: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app